# Bootstrap change button if size changes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, resize

I was wondering how I could change a bootstrap button that has a text and an icon to a button with only an icon when I resize the screen to a low size.

Here's my button

```
  <a class="btn btn-default col-md-2 "href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-lg"></i>  Twitter</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter

you need to put the text into a span tag and add any of these classes: hidden-xs, hidden-sm, hidden-md or hidden-lg depending on the size of the window where you what the text to be hidden, and you also need to set the height of the button